# Html coding-Visual composer stm testemonials

Tags: html, composer-php

I need some help in html coding.
I am the owner of this site http://www.reussirlegmat.com/
In my home page, there is a section in the bottom of the page under the name of "Temoingnages". The section shows 2 testimonials in one row, and 2 arrows who help the visitor see the other testimonials. 
I was to have 4 shown testimonials instead of 2, divided in two rows. which means 2 testimonials per row  plus the arrows to scroll to the other testimonials. 
I have to clue how to do that. I am using visual composer and the testimonials section is added by an stm file. I can use ftp to access my html code.
Can you please help me to adjust the needed code and get what I want?